# PHP escapeshellarg on Windows for percent sign

Tags: php, windows, escaping

On Windows, `escapeshellarg` replaces all percent signs with space:

```
$ php -r "echo escapeshellarg('%');";
" "
```

Someone else also [mentioned this on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php#74815):

> Under Windows, this function puts string into double-quotes, not
>   single, and replaces %(percent sign) with a space, that's why it's
>   impossible to pass a filename with percents in its name through this
>   function.

I want to still use `escapeshellarg` and also allow for percent sign characters. In batch you would escape a percent sign with another percent sign:

```
$ echo %%test%%
%test%
```

Obviously, you could do this by replacing the percent signs with something unique, then calling `escapeshellarg` and then putting the percent signs back:

```
<?php
$arg = '%';
$uid = uniqid();
echo str_replace($uid, '%%', escapeshellarg(str_replace('%', $uid, $arg)));
// outputs: "%%"
```

So, is there any known workaround to bypass this limitation and still use 
`escapeshellarg`?

Comment: One workaround I've done is to pipe in an argument through stdin. I'm very much not happy with that workaround. This to me is a huge limitation of PHP

Answer (score 0):

This link has a good explanation about the shortcomings of PHPs sanitization API: https://gist.github.com/Zenexer/40d02da5e07f151adeaeeaa11af9ab36

> It's impossible to write a universal shell escaping function, for a variety of reasons.

Basically it looks like `escapeshellarg` is not adequately safe anyways.

I've been using stdin to get past this. It's a crumby workaround but it's gotten the job done for me.